# display mulitple images one after the other in my ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-file

Currently my code displays a single image from a file path (in SDCard). This is in `onCreate()` method for now:

```
 ImageView imgView01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
 File dir = new File("/sdcard/WallpapersHD/");
 File file[]=dir.listFiles();
 for (int i=0;i<file.length;i++) {
      Drawable d = (Drawable) Drawable.createFromPath(file[i].toString());
      imgView01.setImageDrawable(d);
      }
```

I want to display all the images in that particular folder one after the other using a time delay of say 5 seconds. If I can create a new drawable for each image in the folder, How do I do it? and how do I change the image in `ImageView` to set that drawable's path?

Comment: I think what happens is that your code flips through all the images very quickly in the loop and then just ends up showing the last one. You need some sort of delay between changing them, but you can't add that in onCreate as it would make your app unresponsive, you need to do that in a separate thread.

Comment: What you are saying is exactly what's happening. Its flipping through all the images quickly and just displaying the last one. So how do I implement delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [ImageSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html) for convenience, and then do:

```
    imageSwitcher.postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    i++;
                    imageSwitcher.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file[i]));
                    imageSwitcher.postDelayed(this, millisBetweenImages);
                }
            },
            millisBetweenImages);
```

it also has a setImageDrawable-method if you want to keep your images as Drawables.

Comment: getting this error : The method setImageURI(Uri) in the type ImageSwitcher is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: My mistake, it takes a Uri-object as it's argument, not a String, you can use Uri.fromFile() in this case I assume.

Comment: Thanks for that! Now the app just force closes due to a nullpointer exception :   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11208):     at android.widget.ImageSwitcher.setImageURI(ImageSwitcher.java:48)

Comment: Either you have an empty entry in file[], or you have not created the ImageSwitcher properly. It is not very well documented, but I am quite certain it needs two ImageViews as children in the layout xml.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped! I had not put any Imageview children under the imageswitcher. Now I'm able to display one image only. It does not switch automatically. My millisBetweenImages=2000. Seems to me that "imageSwitcher.postDelayed(this, 2000);" is not working

Comment: Strange, it works for me when I try it. Make sure that you don't zero the value of i anywhere in your code.

Comment: Perfect! I had initialized i=0 in my code. Works great now! thanks a lot! Small issue.. When I put a different folder with more images (say 100), the app force closes due to "outOfMemory" error. Is there any method which I can call on imageSwitcher to avoid this?

Comment: I'm unsure, but you could possibly try to get hold of the previous image and call recycle() on it before assigning a new image.

Comment: Ok, will try to figure that out. I can't call recycle on the image object i think. I can call recycle() only on bitmap objects. But I'm not converting into a bitmap before displaying it. Ok, I'll try both and write a comment here. Will also accept your answer. Meanwhile, let me know if u find a better / robust way as to how i should prolly go about in doing it.

Comment: you can however access the bitmaps used by the views like so: ImageView v = (ImageView)imageSwitcher.getNextView(); BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable(); Bitmap b = bd.getBitmap(); And then call b.recycle(); followed by setting the new image. I don't know if this is the best approach, but it is worth a try.

Comment: Tried that. But now getting a NullPointerException at Bitmap b=bd.getBitmap(); I've also started a new question on SO regarding the same problem. Lets see what happens.

Comment: Ok, If I can think of a better solution I'll post it there then.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing; Don't forget that you now have all of the ImageSwitchers nifty animation-controls. You can make the images animate in and out in a specific way (fading or sliding for example) by calling its setInAnimation() and setOutAnimation(), and they will automaticly animate everytime you set a new image.

Comment: I redid my program just using a single imageview. I just re-sized and scaled down the sizes of the images so that the memory consumption is reduced. Now there is no problem in displaying images one after the other. Will put the full approach here when it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable for each image, and then keep changing the image in your ImageView, perhaps in a Handler or TimerTask.